# How can I replace all special characters in a cell except for spaces and dashes in Google Sheets using regex?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble using a regex expression to replace all special characters in a cell except for spaces and dashes and was wondering if someone could help.

I'm trying different variations and I'm able to do the following.

- Replace all special characters, but words like "what's" turn into "what s ".
- Replace all non-word characters but getting no spaces between words.

If anyone could help here that would be great. I just want my regex expression to replace all special characters in a cell except for spaces and dashes. If it can be done without a regex formula that would be great too. Thanks a bunch in advance for all the help!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the responses. Tried both and they both did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: hi @dunbirdcrew, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to set the special characters you want to remove/replace since you can control which ones are the characters to be removed.

#### Formula:

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[!@#$%^&*()]", "")`

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

Or set the characters only allowed. (replace all characters that are not numbers, letters, space and dash)

#### Formula:

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^0-9a-zA-Z -]", "")`

#### Sample:

[image: sample2]

#### Reference:

- For the syntax google is using, see [link](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]", "")`
That will remove all characters that aren't a letter, a digit, a dash or a space.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LLL9hKdm035fikv96KjP3sAZTIcKs4GqBuxWHHsVO7g/edit?usp=sharing
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not sure what difference this is from the posted answer before this one. Also, this replaces next lines and tabs (other white spaces) which is not included in OP's post

Comment: @NaziA edited it about the same time I posted this.

Comment: Unless you want to also replace next lines and tabs, you need to refrain from using `\s`

Comment: You're right, @NaziA, this doesn't remove newlines. To remove newlines and tabs, use `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\ ]", "")`